# how to retrieve data from multiple imshow calls?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using imshow to show several layers of data on a single ax:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,30))
ax.imshow(data_matrix1, extent=extent, cmap=color_maps[1], alpha=0.6, interpolation='none')
ax.imshow(data_matrix2, extent=extent, cmap=color_maps[2], alpha=0.6, interpolation='none')
ax.imshow(data_matrix3, extent=extent, cmap=color_maps[3], alpha=0.6, interpolation='none')
```

is there a way to get the final result as a matrix of values? (would like to avoid computing this matrix from the individual matrices, since retaining/computing the coloring overlay added in each step will be tricky)